# golang: build command-line-arguments: cannot find module for path x

Tags: go

I am getting an issue running a function from a non-main package in main.go

```
// main.go
package main

import test "./tests"

func main() {
    test.Test("hello world")
}


// (relative to main.go) ./tests/test.go
package test

import "fmt"

func Test(str string) {
    fmt.Println(str)
}
```

Output:
`build command-line-arguments: cannot find module for path _/c_/Users/Mike/Desktop/random/tests`

Comment: Do not use relative imports in Go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Go 1.16+ use Go modules:

1. Exec `go mod init projectname`
2. Replace `import test "./tests"` by
   `import test "projectname/tests"`